# Logic Pro X: Output 3-4 is disabled

Tags: logic-pro

I have my kick drum sent to a bus. And there is an EQ on there. This bus has no "output".

This bus is used as a side channel input for a compressor in my bass track.

But something is wrong so I would to hear that side channel. In real life, I would "cue" that channel straight to the headphone jack and hear it. In Logic I was expecting to set the output to "Channel 3-4" and set my external USB audio output as the target for that.

However, in my Logic I am not able to set the output to Channel 3-4 and also from the application preferences it seems I may only use one stereo output.

[image]

[image]

To clarify: in Logic / Preferences / Devices I am able to select this output device and play to it. In this circumstance I am still limited to 2 channels.

Answer (score 1):

You have not told us the make and model of your external USB audio interface device.

I cannot troubleshoot this for your thoroughly on this site, but it seems to me that the problem is with the configuration of your USB audio interface. Logic cannot see that your third-party external interface has a Channel 3 and a Channel 4 outputs.

Look into the owner's manual for your third-party audio interface and find out if it needs a specific driver installed, and/or how to configure it to work properly with your Mac (using the **Audio MIDI Setup** app in the **Applications: Utilities** folder or elsewhere.) Then find out where to check Logic Pro X's global preference settings to make sure that Logic Pro is properly configured to recognize and use all the inputs and outputs on your external hardware. You may need to quit Logic and start it up again for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated the question to clarify that output to this device does work.

Comment: You have still not identified the make and model of the external USB audio interface, and for that matter you have not specified which version of Mac OS X you are using, or which version of Logic Pro X. We need all that information.